# Reading registry on a remote computer using its IP address -- strange behavior of OpenRemoteBaseKey

Tags: .net, windows, powershell, registry

I'm trying to write an application that will get some registry values from a remote computer. The user can provide a hostname or IP in a string and should be getting a registry value displayed on their screen. When I was debugging the program, it turned out that it gives an error whenever the input I provide is either "localhost" or "127.0.0.1", but it works when I provide "mxcz", which is my computer name.

The application uses the OpenRemoteRegistryKey method in Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey. I decided to isolate this line and just run it in PowerShell. You can see what happens in the picture below. These two PowerShell lines work:

```
[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey([Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]::LocalMachine,127.0.0.1)

[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey([Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]::LocalMachine,"mxcz")
```

These don't work:

```
[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey([Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]::LocalMachine,"127.0.0.1")

[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey([Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]::LocalMachine,localhost)

[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey([Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]::LocalMachine,"localhost")
```

Using my actual LAN IP address 192.168.0.136 instead of 127.0.0.1 gives the exact same behavior. It works without the quotes and doesn't work in quotes.

It's clear to me, I think, why the second line works and why the fourth line doesn't. But I can't figure out why the first line works and why the third and the fifth don't. The Microsoft webpage for the OpenRemoteRegistryKey method clearly says that the second argument is supposed to be a string. Why doesn't "localhost" in quotes work then? Why does 127.0.0.1 without quotes work? I don't understand how the method interprets this value. Why doesn't "127.0.0.1" in quotes work?

And most importantly, how can I pass whatever the method needs to it, when the user input is a string, either "hostname" or "ipaddress" (preferably using the same variable regardless of which one the user decides to use)? Simply feeding it a string with the value "127.0.0.1" clearly doesn't work. Or should I use a different way of accessing a remote registry altogether?

This is on Windows 8.1, x64.

[image]

**EDIT**

In C# neither the quoted nor the unquoted version works. With the quotes, it will give the same error, "network path not found", and without them it won't compile, see below.

[image]

Comment: I would expect your first example to fail. Are you _really_ sure that was working?

Comment: @Matt Me too... And it does fail to even compile in C#. But it's the only thing that actually works for IP addresses anywhere that I can see.

Comment: There are good reasons for all of these. I don't know why you would want to open remote key to yourself though.

Comment: @Matt If you could elaborate on the reasons, and help me with my problem, please do. I can see the edit to your first comment. Yes, I am sure it's working.I am actually able to read registry values this way in PowerShell. Not in C# of course.

Comment: What is your version of PowerShell? Your first example fails for me. Getting localhost is a matter of passing an empty string `""`. From technet _The local machine registry is opened if machineName is String.Empty._ Perhaps it is ignoring host file... that is where local host comes from.

Comment: @Matt My version of Powershell is 4. Localhost is not the issue here. I need to be able to use IP addresses as well as hostnames and I'm not.

Comment: You definitely have to quotes them or powershell will try and evaluate it as something other than what it is. I don't want to say bug but there is something missing here we are no seeing..... Is remote registry turned on??... no that cant be it....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is the error is misleading. One of the [prerequisites of this working](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8zha3xws(v=vs.110).aspx) is that the remote registry service needs to be running.

> In order for a key to be opened remotely, both the server and client machines must be running the remote registry service, and have remote administration enabled.

I would suggest on your own machine and target machines that you verify that service is running. I was able to replicate the issue by toggling the service off and on. When the method assumes localhost it works by accessing locally it seems. When it is explicitly stated it appears to attempt to use the service.

Also you have to quote those string. Else PowerShell will attempt to evaluate the text as an exe/function/cmdlet etc. Just type in `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` and you will get errors from the parser. In the case of the latter:

```
The property '0.1' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists.
```

This is the same error I get for one of your working examples... which unfortunately doesnt seem to help

```
PS D:\temp> [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey([Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]::LocalMachine,127.0.0.1)
The property '0.1' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists.
At line:1 char:1
+ [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey([Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]: ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], PropertyNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFoundStrict
```

Comment: Not sure about the example where you type in 127.0.0.1 without quotes though.....

Comment: You're a genius! It never occurred to me that the remote registry service could have anything to do with it. It doesn't make sense to me even now that it does it locally sometimes and uses the service at other times, but it worked! I had to run Visual Studio as admin also. But these are not going to be issues at work, where remote registry runs everywhere by default and people (including me) have UAC disabled. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that powershell is handling the 127.0.0.1 without quotes weirdly. If you crack open powershell and type 127.0.0.1 by itself, it will return with no output and no error.  If you try to do something like "> 127.0.0.1 | gm" it will throw an exception.

I noticed then that doing anything with more than two periods is treated differently. Try typing "127.0" at the prompt and then "127.0.0" at the prompt. Different behavior.

Finally - try this:

```
ping 127.0.0.1 #works
ping (127.0.0.1)  #doesn't work -- powershell doing something weird
ping 8.8.8.8 # works 
ping (8.8.8.8) # doesn't work
# the weird part. If you ping after the first octet, ping treats
# anything else as the end... example
# ping 127.1 = "ping 127.0.0.1"  since powershell isn't
# doing it's weirdness on short strings, try:
ping 127.1  # works
ping (127.1) # works
```

So - I think, long story short is PowerShell is doing weird stuff to that IP address without you having to quote it.  Would love some additional info on this from someone who might have dived deeper than I.

Comment: Hi. Yes, I've been experimenting like this too and I can't figure it out at all. The problem is I actually need to be able to get computers by their IP addresses. I could of course reverse-resolve to hostname, but that's not enough in my application because it will be used in an environment where the reverse-resolution will fail a lot of the time.

Comment: You wrapping it in brackets is what is causing the issue. you are creating expressions that powershell is attempting to run. (127.0.0.1) is not a valid number or cmd. The errors you are getting are telling you just that. 127.1 and (127.1) both work because `(127.1)` is a valid expression and a number which is an address that translates to 127.0.0.1

Comment: @Matt thanks for the info - you're right. I was believing that the interpreter was being smart about the format of the IP Address rather than just not throwing an error at me for a malformed floating point number. Good call!

Answer (score 0):

**PowerShell**

I believe this may be due to PowerShell's way of doing Type Inference in earlier versions as i'm not seeing the same results using PowerShell 5 on Windows 10.

PowerShell has it's own unique way of finding out which type you need to use certain .Net methods:

For example:

```
[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey([Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]::LocalMachine,"127.0.0.1")
```

and

```
[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey("LocalMachine","127.0.0.1")
```

are the same, the only difference is that PowerShell translates `"LocalMachine"` to `[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]::LocalMachine` at Runtime because `OpenRemoteBaseKey` requires the first parameter to be of type `Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive`.

Here are some things you can try though:

(1) Let PowerShell evalute a variable first and then pass the variable to `OpenRemoteBaseKey`, PowerShell will evaulate the variable rather than a string:

```
$computer = "127.0.0.1"
[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey("LocalMachine",$computer)
```

(2) Use literal quotes to tell PowerShell you want to pass 127.0.0.1 literally:

```
[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey("LocalMachine",'127.0.0.1')
```

**C#**

The reason it doesn't work in C# is because unlike Powershell 127.0.0.1 without quotes is not valid syntax for anything (As mentioned in the error message).

If you put the IP Address in quotes you will be telling C# which computers LocalMachine you'd like to connect to:

```
RegistryKey fd = RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, @"127.0.0.1");
```

Hope this helps, please let us know if you make any progress :)

Comment: Hello. Unfortunately, both (1) and (1) are giving me the "Network path not found" error message in PowerShell and I'm getting the same error message in C# for your line.

Comment: My Powershell version is 4.